# How do I see bullet drop?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I have seen pro players' gameplay videos in which the bullet can be seen all the way to its impact point. Mostly in long-range shots where a small, flashy dot travels till it hits something. But I cannot see it when I play. Are there any graphic settings I should change?

I play on an i3-6100 processor with a 4 GB 1050 Ti graphics card and 8 GB of 2400 MHz RAM with low-medium graphic settings.

GIF of what I am talking about:

[image: GIF of PUBG bullet drop]

Comment: As far as I know, bullet shots is visible during flight only if you shooting with VSS. In videos you watched player was probably shooting with VSS.

Comment: I think I saw shroud shoot with kar98 once

Answer (score 3):

It also depends on your resolution, I would assume.
And I don't know if you keep scoped in while your shot travels. Because some guns are automatically put down after the shot (e.g. Kar-98k)

To keep your scope zoomed-in, just don't let the left mouse button go after your shot.

Comment: Thats a neat trick I must say. What resolution would you recommend?

Comment: @MandeepJain I play at 2560x1440 and I am able to see the bullets, or at least the bullet impacts quite okay, I'd say - depending on the distance of course.

Comment: You will only see that bullet drop when staying scoped in with snipers that allow it. It shouldn't be a resolution thing.